# Restrict users to certain applications only

Tags: security, ubuntu-12.04, openldap, application

We are using many applications like zabbix, phabricator, AC etc. We need to integrate LDAP in all these applications. These application support LDAP but not group based authentication.

Please let us know is there any option to restrict selected users to login. We created all users under ou ‘users’ .

[image]

On these application we need to login certain users only. How we can restrict it as we can’t able to restrict on application side

In these application they provide only “Base DN” and  “Search Attribute” so we can’t able to give dn: ou=users,ou=system as it gives access to all users.

So is it possible to give Base DN as “cn=Zabbix,ou=groups,ou=system” and this group contains only  user1 and user2. SO it will restrict users.

Please let us know how we can implement this scenario. Thanks in advance please help us to solve this issue.

Thanks

Geo

Comment: Please let me know is it possible to implement this idea?. Also please let me know your thoughts.